# Trying to use PHP match case to perform some condition

Tags: php, laravel, match

Trying to use php match case to perform the below operation and it keep throwing unhandled match case...is it that its not possible or am doing it in a wrong way..need your opinion on how to achieve this even if its outside match case, actually i dont want to use if statement,,i want to use match case, but if its not possible, i will use if or switch case..Thanks

```
  function increaseQuantity($data, $cart){
        try {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $data = match($cart){
                !is_null($cart->product_id)  =>  $this->checkProductQuantityInStore($cart),
                !is_null($cart->meal_plan_id)  =>  $this->checkMealPlanQuantityInStore($cart),
            };
            if($data){
                return $data;
            }
            return $user->carts()->where('id', $cart->id)->increment('quantity', $data['quantity'] ?? 1);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }
    }

{
    "message": "Unhandled match case of type App\\Models\\Cart",
    "exception": "UnhandledMatchError",
```

Comment: match needs to be exhaustive, if you're not meeting the condition it throws an error. you can add a default case to prevent this.

Comment: Writing normal sentences, even in titles, with all upper-case is considered shouting. And its very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: You say you don't want to use `if` or `switch`, but `match`. What is your reason for this preference? Personally, I try to break down the issue in steps. A good step is a simple step. I think you are trying to make a step thats simply too big. First write your logic with `if` statements. When you got it working, translate it into `match`.

Comment: i will switch it to lower case

Comment: okay.. i will write it in if statement then translate it to match...thanks for the advice

Comment: thanks...i've written it as a separate middleware...